# iterating through json file in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm writing this code to find the long-name of `"types" : [ "locality", "political" ]` and long-name of `"types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]` from the json file. but unable to iterate through the array properly

> js file

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=23.6519148,87.13857650000001', function(error, response, data) {
    if (!(!error && response.statusCode == 200)) {
        console.log('error! ');
        return;
    }

    data = JSON.parse(data);
    for (var i in data.results) {
        for (var j in data.results[i]) {
            if (j == 'address_components') {
                console.log('found')
                console.log(data.results[i][j][1]);
                console.log(data.results[i][j][2]);
                for (var k in data.results[i]){
                    if(k == 'long_name')
                        console.log('found')
                }
                console.log('not found')
            }
        }
        break;
    }
});
```

> output

```
found
{ long_name: 'Kunustoria',
  short_name: 'Kunustoria',
  types: [ 'locality', 'political' ] }
{ long_name: 'Bardhaman',
  short_name: 'Bardhaman',
  types: [ 'administrative_area_level_2', 'political' ] }
not found
```

Comment: What do you need as output?

Comment: long_name of "types" : [ "locality", "political" ] and long_name of "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]..... that is "Kunustoria" and "Bardhaman"

Comment: Point of clarity.  Once you execute this line `data = JSON.parse(data);` you are no longer dealing with JSON, but rather a regular JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your for loop with this...

```
data = JSON.parse(data).results;

data.forEach(function (address) {
  console.log(address['address_components'][0].long_name);
});
```

Comment: thanks, this gives the first long name of all the address_components, but I want the 2nd and 3rd long name of 1st address_components. I will try to get that using your loop :)

Answer (score 0):

First you must install lodash.

**npm install --save lodash**

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var data = api_response_from_google_maps;//Assign the api response here.
var addrs = [];
_.map(data.results, function (address) {
  _.map(address.address_components, function (item) {
    if (_.isEqual(item.types, ["locality", "political"]) || _.isEqual(item.types, ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"])) {
      addrs.push(item);
    }
  })
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(addrs));
```

This gives an array of objects of `adresses_components` with `types` array as you specified.